# String IndexOf and Replace in wysiwyg

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg

I'm trying to create a very simple `wysiwyg` editor (without colors), and I've tried creating the "end tag" to one of the beginning tags.

I know that when I use value it won't work since it gets the whole value of the `textarea` so I tried using `string` using `indexOf` and `replace`.

But it seems like the code doesn't work, I've researched about searching pirticular keywords (lets assume it `<html>`) in the `textarea` and replacing it with another (keyword: `<html> </html>`)

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var textarea = document.getElementById('codeTextarea');
    textarea.keyup(function(e) {
        var str = textarea.value;
        if(str.indexOf('<html>') != -1){
            str.replace("<html>", "<html> </html>");
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="codeTextarea"></textarea>
```

How can I replace a particular string in a `textarea` with another string? (I.E: `<html>` will be replaced with `<html> </html>`)

**Notice**

Please don't tell me use value because value can be `<doctype> <html>` and then the wanted code wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code. The first one is that you are using jquery .keyup event which is missing in the normal DOM object. The second problem is that .replace actually returns the result of the replacement. And the third one is that you didn't apply the value to the text area.

```
var textarea = $('#codeTextarea');
textarea.keyup(function(e) {
    var field = $(this);
    var str = field.val();
    if(str.indexOf('<html>') != -1){
        str = str.replace("<html>", "<html> </html>");
    }
    field.val(str);
});
```

However, this code works, but you should rethink using regular expressions. Because once you convert the <html> to <html></html> next time you will get <html></html></html> and so on and so on.

Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ErF4k/1/

And here is another jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ErF4k/3/ which uses regex. That's not my strongest part, but the idea is to match <html> followed by something different then a tag.

```
var textarea = $('#codeTextarea');
textarea.keyup(function(e) {
    var field = $(this);
    var str = field.val();        
    if(str.indexOf('<html>') != -1){
        str = str.replace(/\<html\>([a-z|A-Z|0-9| ])/g, "<html></html>");
    }
    field.val(str);
});
```

Just start typing <html> and press a letter, number or interval.

Comment: I'm sorry for the trouble, but it seems like duplicate html tag with 2 others. you got any solution?

Comment: Yep, that's the effect without using regex. I'm not trying to solve the problem. Will write here once it is done.

Comment: Can you give me example of this regex? or atleast working code? I'll appreciate it!

Comment: Yep. I'm now digging in this, but can't write the correct one.

Comment: Just added it to the answer. It is not perfect, but it works with letters, numbers and interval. Add whatever character you need inside the regex.

Comment: I've notice that I've to make space to make the "end tag" appeare, I would like make it right away, is it possible?

Comment: At the moment I can't give you a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting to set the value of the textarea once you're done replacing the content in the string. Try doing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var textarea = document.getElementById('codeTextarea');
    textarea.keyup(function(e) {
        var str = textarea.value;
        if(str.indexOf('<html>') != -1){
            textarea.value = str.replace("<html>", "<html> </html>");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's not working, I've written html tag but it seems to be fail. Is there any other solution?